# How to apply parallel or asynchronous I/O file writing on a python piece of code

Tags: python, asynchronous, io

To begin with, we're given the following piece of code:

```
from validate_email import validate_email
import time
import os

def verify_emails(email_path, good_filepath, bad_filepath):
    good_emails = open(good_filepath, 'w+')
    bad_emails = open(bad_filepath, 'w+')

    emails = set()

    with open(email_path) as f:
        for email in f:
            email = email.strip()

            if email in emails:
                continue
            emails.add(email)

            if validate_email(email, verify=True):
                good_emails.write(email + '\n')
            else:
                bad_emails.write(email + '\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.system('cls')
    verify_emails("emails.txt", "good_emails.txt", "bad_emails.txt")
```

I expect contacting SMTP servers to be the most expensive part by far from my program when `emails.txt` contains large amount of lines (>1k). Using some form of parallel or asynchronous I/O should speed this up a lot, since I can wait for multiple servers to respond instead of waiting sequentially.

As far as I have read:

> Asynchronous I/O operates by queuing a request for I/O to the file
>   descriptor, tracked independently of the calling process. For a file
>   descriptor that supports asynchronous I/O (raw disk devcies
>   typically), a process can call aio_read() (for instance) to request a
>   number of bytes be read from the file descriptor. The system call
>   returns immediately, whether or not the I/O has completed. Some time
>   later, the process then polls the operating system for the completion
>   of the I/O (that is, buffer is filled with data).

To be sincere, I didn't quite understand how to implement async I/O on my program. Can anybody take a little time and explain me the whole process ?

---

**EDIT** as per PArakleta suggested:

```
from validate_email import validate_email
import time
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import itertools

def validate_map(e):
    return (validate_email(e.strip(), verify=True), e)

seen_emails = set()
def unique(e):
    if e in seen_emails:
        return False
    seen_emails.add(e)
    return True

def verify_emails(email_path, good_filepath, bad_filepath):
    good_emails = open(good_filepath, 'w+')
    bad_emails = open(bad_filepath, 'w+')

    with open(email_path, "r") as f:
        for result in Pool().imap_unordered(validate_map,
                                    itertools.ifilter(unique, f):
        (good, email) = result
        if good:
            good_emails.write(email)
        else:
            bad_emails.write(email)
        good_emails.close()
        bad_emails.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.system('cls')
    verify_emails("emails.txt", "good_emails.txt", "bad_emails.txt")
```

Comment: Not really an answer but have you considered some map-reduce like mechanism instead ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers no, I haven't. Will this be better than what I asked for ? You can elaborate your comment in an answer

Comment: Don't know if it "will be better" but at least you don't have to deal with async io... The idea here would be: 1. split your source file in chunks 2. send each chunk to a subprocess 3. each subprocess write it's own result files (on a location passed in by the main process) 4. when each subprocess is done the master concatenate the results files. It's a very crude and simplistic version of map-reduce but it should be easy to implement and it might even work.

Comment: It sounds like a solution which is closed to threading but it doesn't sound too lightweight because: 1-what happens if I have a file with 200k emails? How many files/chunks I'll have to create? (even 1k lasts over 30mins). 2-I'll have to find the number of lines to know in how many chunks to split the original number of lines. 3- it just sounds inefficient at this moment. But I might be wrong. Would you like to test your theory in an answer ?

Comment: You can always use `wc -l` to get the lines count - on a 200Klines it takes a couple microseconds.... But if you want another solution, you could also use celery with a `validate_email()` task returning both the email and a good/bad flag and the main process writing the results to disk. Or a full-blown map-reduce framework. Or you could write results to a database - SQL or document or key-value or whatever as long as it supports concurrent writes. To make a long story short, the point was you don't necessarily need "async io" to solve your problem...

Comment: Is the question "how do I implement async I/O?" or is it "how do I make my code faster?"

Comment: @Alexander is there something you don't like or understand about my answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### You're asking the wrong question

Having looked at the `validate_email` package your real problem is that you're not efficiently batching your results.  You should be only doing the MX lookup once per domain and then only connect to each MX server once, go through the handshake, and then check all of the addresses for that server in a single batch.  Thankfully the `validate_email` package does the MX result caching for you, but you still need to be group the email addresses by server to batch the query to the server itself.

You need to edit the `validate_email` package to implement batching, and then probably give a thread to each domain using the actual `threading` library rather than `multiprocessing`.

It's always important to profile your program if it's slow and figure out where it is actually spending the time rather than trying to apply optimisation tricks blindly.

#### The requested solution

IO is already asynchronous if you are using buffered IO and your use case fits with the OS buffering.  The only place you could potentially get some advantage is in read-ahead but Python already does this if you use the iterator access to a file (which you are doing).  AsyncIO is an advantage to programs that are moving large amounts of data and have disabled the OS buffers to prevent copying the data twice.

You need to actually profile/benchmark your program to see if it has any room for improvement.  If your disks aren't already throughput bound then there is a chance to improve the performance by parallel execution of the processing of each email (address?).  The easiest way to check this is probably to check to see if the core running your program is maxed out (i.e. you are CPU bound and not IO bound).

If you are CPU bound then you need to look at threading.  Unfortunately Python threading doesn't work in parallel unless you have non-Python work to be done so instead you'll have to use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) (I'm assuming `validate_email` is a Python function).

How exactly you proceed depends on where the bottleneck's in your program are and how much of a speed up you need to get to the point where you are IO bound (since you cannot actually go any faster than that you can stop optimising when you hit that point).

The `emails` set object is hard to share because you'll need to lock around it so it's probably best that you keep that in one thread.  Looking at the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library the easiest mechanism to use is probably [Process Pools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool).

Using this you would need to wrap your file iterable in an [`itertools.ifilter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) which discards duplicates, and then feed this into a [`Pool.imap_unordered`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered) and then iterate that result and write into your two output files.

Something like:

```
with open(email_path) as f:
    for result in Pool().imap_unordered(validate_map,
                                        itertools.ifilter(unique, f):
        (good, email) = result
        if good:
            good_emails.write(email)
        else:
            bad_emails.write(email)
```

The `validate_map` function should be something simple like:

```
def validate_map(e):
    return (validate_email(e.strip(), verify=True), e)
```

The `unique` function should be something like:

```
seen_emails = set()
def unique(e):
    if e in seen_emails:
        return False
    seen_emails.add(e)
    return True
```

---

**ETA**: I just realised that `validate_email` is a library which actually contacts SMTP servers.  Given that it's not busy in Python code you can use threading.  The [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) API though is not as convenient as the multiprocessing library but you can use [multiprocessing.dummy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) to have a thread based Pool.

If you are CPU bound then it's not really worth having more threads/processes than cores but since your bottleneck is network IO you can benefit from many more threads/processes.  Since processes are expensive you want to swap to threads and then crank up the number running in parallel (although you should be polite not to DOS-attack the servers you are connecting to).

Consider `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool` and then call `ThreadPool(processes=32).imap_unordered()`.

Comment: I am sorry for the late response but just now I tried your solution. Unfortunately, all the emails are sent to `bad_emails.txt` even though there are some that should be sent to `good_emails.txt`.

Comment: @Alexander If I disable the DNS and SMTP checks it works fine, I assumed the other problems were with my firewall, it's somewhat aggressive.  I just double checked the MX check and you have to pass `e.strip()` to the `validate_email` function.  I still couldn't test further because I cannot open an SMTP port.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. However, if the program works, it isn't far faster than my previous version. What I'm interested in, is the last part of your answer ( the one with `multiprocessing.dummy`. Where exactly should I put the `ThreadPool...` ? I'll post the actual code which uses your idea and then you can tell me where exactly to implemet what you said.

Comment: @Alexander replace the `from multiprocessing import Pool` with the `multiprocessing.dummy` version, and in `for result in Pool().imap_unordered` change to `for result in ThreadPool(processes=32).imap_unordered` as explained at the end of my answer.  The speedup you get will depend on a lot of factors, for example my DNS server throttles excessive queries so when I parallelise this code my DNS server goes into anti-DOS mode and then the code actually runs slower.  This is why I suggested you'd need to restructure the `validate_emails` library instead.

Comment: Thanks for all your help :) You deserve the bounty